# Splitting length of input mask number sets

Tags: javascript, string-formatting

How would I go about splitting the numbers differently here, like XXX-XXX-XXXX?

```
String.prototype.toCardFormat = function () {
    return this.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").substr(0, 16).split("").reduce(cardFormat, "");
    function cardFormat(str, l, i) {
        return str + ((!i || (i % 4)) ? "" : "-") + l;
    }
};
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alano/K78A5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link to updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K78A5/78/). Add an OR condition to your function.

```
 function cardFormat(str, l, i) {
    return str + ((!i || (i % 3) || i > 8) ? "" : "-") + l;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd change the conditions under which an `-` is appended. Above, it's every 4 characters. Here, it's after the 3rd and 6th:

```js
String.prototype.toCardFormat = function() {
  return this.
    replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").
    substr(0, 16).
    split("").
    reduce(cardFormat, "");

  function cardFormat(str, l, i) {
    return str + 
           (((i == 3) || (i == 6)) ? "-" : "") + 
           l;
  }
};

var st = "1234567890";

console.log(st.toCardFormat());
```

Comment: This didn't work for me for some reason, but thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Interesting. I plugged it into [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y60btLha/1/) and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I tried it again and it works, so sorry. Your answer works. Thank you for your help.